# SVG.js: large bounds SVG's don't show up?

Tags: svg, svg.js

I have this code which works perfectly.

```
<html>
        <header>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.4/svg.min.js"></script>
                <script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.get('Arctic_big.svg', function(data) {
                var draw = SVG('svgimage').size(300,300);
                var svg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
                var rect = draw.svg(svg);
                //draw.svg(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data));
        });
});
                </script>
        </header>
        <body>
                <div style="width:100%" id="svgimage"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I can see the map in the browser. However when I try big-svg.svg it doesn't work. in fact when I look at the html it renders it gives an empty svg:

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="2" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" style="overflow: hidden; top: -100%; left: -100%; position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><defs id="SvgjsDefs1002"></defs><polyline id="SvgjsPolyline1003" points="0,0"></polyline><path id="SvgjsPath1004" d="M0 0 "></path></svg>
```

The Arctic_big.svg is a bigger file but the bounds of the big-svg.svg are pretty big - its on a huge coordinate space. I might need to scale it somehow so that it fits but if its not even making any objects, I don't think this is the issue. Also its using paths instead of polylines. Any advice/help on getting this big-svg.svg to render in svg.js?

1. Arctic_big.svg: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arctic_big.svg#/media/File:Arctic_big.svg
2. big-svg.svg:
   hosted here: https://pastebin.com/Cns1uJ6i

Comment: Shouldn't it be `draw.svg(svg)` (without paranthesis)?

Comment: @ccprog yes sorry I copied the entire code file to ensure that its the correct working version now

Comment: I had issues with browsers not showing my file when the coordinates where to big. You also might want to adjust the viewbox - that's how you actually can shrink it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: If you remove the size (width and height) attributes from the SVG you are importing, you should find it works like you expect. The picture below shows what it will look like.

```
<svg width="196812.5" height="55975" viewBox="662.5 375 196812.5 55975" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;fill:none">
```

VS:

```
<svg viewBox="662.5 375 196812.5 55975" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;fill:none">
```

Width and height attributes in SVG (weirdly) actually describe the number of pixels. Since the nice thing about svg is it is resolution independent, I'm not sure what the logic behind that is. Anyway, it is the viewBox numbers that give you your coordinate space and allow to use arbitrary units for drawing.

I think the best thing for most cases is to use SVG without width or height, and depend only on the viewBox. I think a lot of graphics programs are kind of designed with print in mind, so they set absolute sizes when saving svg images.

[Picture of different size attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGG8q.png)

TOP: Artic_big with width/height

MIDDLE:Artic_big without width/height

BOTTOM: Big-svg without width/height